# Tomcat webapp hanging on Bean Registration

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

I'm trying to deploy a war file that I put in the webapps directory.  The logfile seems to indicate that everything goes OK until this step:

```
2015-08-10 16:33:25,944 INFO  [MBeanExporter.java:412] : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
```

And it just hangs there until the server startup timeout hits.  I have no idea what could be causing this or where to look since no error gets thrown.

Comment: Have you tried to increase your server timeout configuration?

Comment: I had the server timeout as high as 10 minutes and it still happened.  I notice this same line in the log elsewhere and it never takes more than a few seconds in the other webapps.

Comment: did you activate the jmxremote of your tomcat ?

Comment: This is on a fresh install of tomcat 7.0.63, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hangup was related to some issue other than JMX.  See this userlist discussion:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/onebusaway-developers/RDX1n8zVl4U